# Sum columns with the same name

Tags: r

I have transposed my data and ended up with columns with identical names:

```
       id    x     y      z    x     y     z     x     y     z
X1  40634   106   193    78    24    32    46   102   213    89
X2  40664    97   223    77    21    20    51   110   195    83
X3  40695   101   221    66    25    37    52    98   222    64
X4  40725   112   219    67    28    24    36   110   233    70
X5  40756    95   228    72    33    16    57   115   253   114
X6  40787   100   217    65    27    33    32   130   210    93
X7  40817   106   205    59    27    23    39    98   221    67
X8  40848    66   209    74    20    25    45    69   190    94
X9  40878    60   205    80    24    25    45    54   186    79
X10 40909    61   227    66    13    29    43    81   215    76
```

The "x", "y" and "z" columns repeat almost 50 times. I would like to sum the values in columns which have the same name. The result would look something like this (I know the columns are not added, but I need them to):

```
     id     x     y      z
1  40634   106   193    78
2  40664    97   223    77
3  40695   101   221    66
4  40725   112   219    67
5  40756    95   228    72
6  40787   100   217    65
7  40817   106   205    59
```

What's the best way to achieve this in R? Might be something simple but just can't get it right.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this?

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:3), x = c(1:3), y = c(2:4), x = 4:6, y = 6:8)
names(df) <- c("id","x","y","x","y")
names(df)
sapply(df, class)
df
sapply(split.default(df, names(df)), rowSums, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. However, this solution does't work for me. Error ```Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 'x' must be numeric```.

Comment: It seems when after transposing the data, it turns everything to factors including the integers.

Comment: Try this before summarizing: [sapply(df, as.numeric)]

Comment: Seems I am not doing something right, still. same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
cols <- setdiff(names(df), "id")
lapply(cols, function(x) rowSums(df[names(df) == x]))
df[cols] <- lapply(cols, function(x) rowSums(df[names(df) == x]))
df <- df[c("id", cols)]

       id   x   y   z
X1  40634 232 438 213
X2  40664 228 438 211
X3  40695 224 480 182
X4  40725 250 476 173
X5  40756 243 497 243
X6  40787 257 460 190
X7  40817 231 449 165
X8  40848 155 424 213
X9  40878 138 416 204
X10 40909 155 471 185
```

Reproducible data (please provide yourself next time):

```
df <- read.table(
  text = "id    x     y      z    x     y     z     x     y     z
  X1  40634   106   193    78    24    32    46   102   213    89
  X2  40664    97   223    77    21    20    51   110   195    83
  X3  40695   101   221    66    25    37    52    98   222    64
  X4  40725   112   219    67    28    24    36   110   233    70
  X5  40756    95   228    72    33    16    57   115   253   114
  X6  40787   100   217    65    27    33    32   130   210    93
  X7  40817   106   205    59    27    23    39    98   221    67
  X8  40848    66   209    74    20    25    45    69   190    94
  X9  40878    60   205    80    24    25    45    54   186    79
  X10 40909    61   227    66    13    29    43    81   215    76"
)

names(df) <- c("id", rep(c("x", "y", "z"), 3))
```