# Sum row-wise values that are grouped by column name but keep all columns in R?

Tags: r, matrix, group-by, data-manipulation

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35626945/row-wise-sum-of-values-grouped-by-columns-with-same-name) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63777162/sum-columns-with-the-same-name), however, my question is slightly different from those questions. In the other questions, after they sum by the groups, they are removing the 'duplicate' columns. I want to keep the duplicate columns. For example, if I have a matrix that looks like this:

```
myMat <- matrix(NA, 3, 4)
colnames(myMat) <- c('x', 'y', 'x', 'y')
myMat[1,] <- c(1,2,0,1)
myMat[2,] <- c(2,4,3,5)
myMat[3,] <- c(3,6,1,7)

> myMat
     x y x y
[1,] 1 2 0 1
[2,] 2 4 3 5
[3,] 3 6 1 7
```

I want to row-wise sum, grouped by column name. In the links above, one of the answers suggest this:

```
> t(rowsum(t(myMat), group = colnames(myMat), na.rm = T))
     x  y
[1,] 1  3
[2,] 5  9
[3,] 4 13
```

But as you can see, they are combining the columns with the same name together and, as a result, reducing the number of columns. I want to sum the values, but still have the same columns. For example, my desired output would look like this:

```
     x  y x  y
[1,] 1  3 1  3
[2,] 5  9 5  9
[3,] 4 13 4 13
```

In the above, the rows (grouped by name) are summed... but I still have each individual column. Any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `ave` like below (with aids of `col` + `row`)

```
> ave(myMat,colnames(myMat)[col(myMat)], row(myMat), FUN = sum)
     x  y x  y
[1,] 1  3 1  3
[2,] 5  9 5  9
[3,] 4 13 4 13
```

Comment: Output should be 4 columns

Answer (score 2):

Use `ave` and `apply`:

```r
t(apply(myMat, 1, \(x) ave(x, names(x), FUN = sum)))
```

```r
     x  y x  y
[1,] 1  3 1  3
[2,] 5  9 5  9
[3,] 4 13 4 13
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also just take your original solution and cbind it to itself

```
sums =  t(rowsum(t(myMat), group = colnames(myMat), na.rm = T))
cbind(sums, sums)

     x  y x  y
[1,] 1  3 1  3
[2,] 5  9 5  9
[3,] 4 13 4 13
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop would achieve this:

```r
for(i in unique(colnames(myMat))) {
  myMat[,colnames(myMat) == i] <- rowSums(myMat[,colnames(myMat) == i])
}

myMat
#>      x  y x  y
#> [1,] 1  3 1  3
#> [2,] 5  9 5  9
#> [3,] 4 13 4 13
```